# Java non-recursive filesystem walking

Tags: java

I need to create app which uses non-recursive walk through filesystem and prints out files which are on a certain depth.
What I have:

```
public void putFileToQueue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
File root = new File(rootPath).getAbsoluteFile();
checkFile(root, depth);
    Queue<DepthControl> queue = new ArrayDeque<DepthControl>();
    DepthControl e = new DepthControl(0, root);
    do {
        root = e.getFileName();

        if (root.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = root.listFiles();

            if (files != null)
                for (File file : files) {

                    if (e.getDepth() + 1 <= depth && file.isDirectory()) {
                        queue.offer(new DepthControl(e.getDepth() + 1,file));
                    }

                    if (file.getName().contains(mask)) {
                        if (e.getDepth() == depth) {
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                    + " putting in queue: "
                                    + file.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    }
                }
                } 
        e = queue.poll();
    } while (e != null);
}
```

And helper class

```
public class DepthControl {

    private int depth;
    private File file;

    public DepthControl(int depth, File file) {

        this.depth = depth;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public File getFileName() {
        return file;
    }

    public int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }
}
```

I received answer, that this program uses additional memory because of Breadth-first search(hope right translation). I have O(k^n), where k - average amount of subdirectories, n - depth. This program could be easily done with O(k*n). Please help me to fix my algorithm.

Comment: Why does it need to be non-recursive?

Comment: @HotLicks, It's probably a homework-related requirement.

Comment: Just for complication, I think. It is interview task.

Comment: But that's an important question to ask, in real life.  The reason for not wanting a recursive routine might also be a reason for not wanting some other scheme.

Comment: @Hot Licks, also I figured out that non-recursive walking is faster, because we don't need to execute function repeatedly. Maybe we could have problems with out of memory using recursion.

Comment: Technically, the recursive routine need be no slower or take more memory than the other options, though in practice you're probably right.  But the difference would be negligible, and out-of-memory is a possibility with any scheme.

Comment: I can put whole project here, which hepled me to receive my first job, if someone is interested. Thanks, everybody

Comment: @HotLicks: Non-recursive file walking avoids StackOverflowErrors, which can occur with extremely deep folder hierarchies.

Comment: @pythondude -- I said "take more memory".  Stack overflow occurs because memory is somewhat artificially partitioned into two classes, and the one class runs out.  And see my earlier comment -- it's important, when told to do it without recursion, to know ***why*** that was requested.  That was my point.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should do the job and is a bit simpler. It just keeps track of files at next level, expands them, then repeats the process. The algorithm itself keeps track of depth so there is no need for that extra class.

```
// start in home directory.
File root = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

List<File> expand = new LinkedList<File>();
expand.add(root);

for (int depth = 0; depth < 10; depth++) {
    File[] expandCopy = expand.toArray(new File[expand.size()]);
    expand.clear();
    for (File file : expandCopy) {
        System.out.println(depth + " " + file);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            expand.addAll(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty nice and beautiful. I'll try this.

Comment: but perfomance is terrible because of copying every iteration, but still beautiful code.

Comment: I usually value beauty over performance unless particular performance requirement. The limiting factor will prob be the filesystem in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, you can use stream, Files.walk and a maxDepth of 1

```
    try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get(filePath), 1)) {

        List<String> result = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(Path::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid recursion when walking a tree there are basically two options:

1. Use a "work list" (similar to the above) to track work to be done.  As each item is examined new work items that are "discovered" as a result are added to the work list (can be FIFO, LIFO, or random order -- doesn't matter conceptually though it will often affect "locality of reference" for performance).
2. Use a stack/"push down list" so essentially simulate the recursive scheme.

For #2 you have to write an algorithm that is something of a state machine, returning to the stack after every step to determine what to do next.  The stack entries, for a tree walk, basically contain the current tree node and the index into the child list of the next child to examine.

Comment: I got the idea, but still cann't get how it would work faster

Comment: The three schemes (recursive and the above two) should have the same "big-O" efficiency, since each will visit each node exactly once.  Scheme #1 will use more storage -- O(n) (n = the total number of nodes) on average, I suspect, while recursion and scheme #2 would be O(log n), I think.  (I haven't sat down to work out the efficiency in detail.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to limit the amount of space used and:

- you can assume the list of files/directories is static over the course of your traversal, AND
- you can assume the list of files/directories in a give directory are always returned in the same order
- you have access to the parent of the current directory

Then you can traverse the directory using only the information of the last node visited. Specifically, something along the lines of

```
1. Keep track of the last Entry (directory or file) visited
2. Keep track of the current directory
3. Get a list of files in the current directory
4. Find the index of the last Entry visited in the list of files
5. If lastVisited is the last Entry in the current directory, 
5.1.1 If current directory == start directory, we're done
5.1.2 Otherwise, lastVisited = the current directory and current directory is the parent directory
5.2. Otherwise, visit the element after lastVisited and set lastVisited to that element
6. Repeat from step 3
```

If I can, I'll try to write up some code to show what I mean tomorrow... but I just don't have the time right now.

**NOTE**: This isn't a GOOD way to traverse the directory structure... its just a possible way. Outside the normal box, and probably for good reason.

You'll have to forgive me for not giving sample code in Java, I don't have the time to work on that atm. Doing it in Tcl is faster for me and it shouldn't be too hard to understand. So, that being said:

```
proc getFiles {dir} {
    set result {}
    foreach entry [glob -tails -directory $dir * .*] {
        if { $entry != "." && $entry != ".." } {
            lappend result [file join $dir $entry]
        }
    }
    return [lsort $result]
}

proc listdir {startDir} {
    if {! ([file exists $startDir] && [file isdirectory $startDir])} {
        error "File '$startDir' either doesn't exist or isnt a directory"
    }
    set result {}
    set startDir [file normalize $startDir]
    set currDir $startDir
    set currFile {}

    set fileList [getFiles $currDir]
    for {set i 0} {$i < 1000} {incr i} { # use for to avoid infinate loop
        set index [expr {1 + ({} == $currFile ? -1 : [lsearch $fileList $currFile])}]
        if {$index < ([llength $fileList])} {
            set currFile [lindex $fileList $index]
            lappend result $currFile
            if { [file isdirectory $currFile] } {
                set currDir $currFile
                set fileList [getFiles $currDir]
                set currFile {}
            }
        } else {
            # at last entry in the dir, move up one dir
            if {$currDir == $startDir} {
                # at the starting directory, we're done
                return $result
            }
            set currFile $currDir
            set currDir [file dirname $currDir]
            set fileList [getFiles $currDir]
        }
    }
}

puts "Files:\n\t[join [listdir [lindex $argv 0]] \n\t]"
```

And, running it:

```
VirtualBox:~/Programming/temp$ ./dirlist.tcl /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor
Files:
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/16x16
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/16x16/status
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/16x16/status/audio-input-microphone-high.png
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/16x16/status/audio-input-microphone-low.png
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/16x16/status/audio-input-microphone-medium.png
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/16x16/status/audio-input-microphone-muted.png
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/22x22
    [snip]
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/48x48/devices/audio-subwoofer-testing.svg
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/48x48/devices/audio-subwoofer.svg
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/scalable
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/scalable/status
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/audio-input-microphone-high.svg
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/audio-input-microphone-low.svg
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/audio-input-microphone-medium.svg
    /usr/share/gnome-media/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/audio-input-microphone-muted.svg
```

Comment: And what about just changing the collection to stack? It works, and perfomance seems to be better, what's about memory in this case?

Comment: If i got it right it is some kind of persisting state of search. That's what I thought from the beginning, but couldn't realise how to do this. I'll try now. If you have time, please post realisation or give a link where to read about it in more detail. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 7, there is a very elegant method of walking file trees.  You'll need to confirm whether it meets your needs recursion wise though.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;

public  class myFinder extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attr) { }
public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) { }
public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) { }
public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) { }


<snip>

}
```

Essentially it does a depth first walk of the tree and calls certain methods when it enters/exits directories and when it "visits" a file.

I believe this to be specific to Java 7 though.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Comment: It is very useful in real-world app, I think, but not in my case. It uses recursion. :( Still, thank's for post. very useful to watch new features of java.

Answer (score 0):

And - of course - there's always the multi-threaded option to avoid recursion.

1. Create a queue of files.
2. If it's a file add it to the queue.
3. If it's a folder start a new thread to list files in it that also feeds this queue.
4. Get next item.
5. Repeat from 2 as necessary.

Obviously this may not list the files in a predictable order.